Cannot make sense of the solution window with CumulVar and SlackVar used together with OR Tools
I have a routing problem with one vehicle and a number of waypoints (pickups and deliveries).
I can successfully add a time window for each waypoint with:
dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(start_window, end_window)
But I also want to force the vehicle to wait at each wait point to mimic the loading or unloading time. I try to do so with:
dimension.SlackVar(index).SetValue(loading_time)
The solution window I get with only using the CumulVar looks like:
waypoint 1: (10:17, 11:19)
waypoint 2: (11:25, 11:38)
waypoint 3: (11:45, 11:46)
waypoint 4: (11:45, 11:46)
waypoint 5: (11:45, 11:46)
waypoint 6: (11:53, 11:54)
waypoint 7: (12:00, 12:00)

Once adding the SlackVar, it looks like:
waypoint 1: (11:14, 11:14)
waypoint 2: (11:27, 11:27)
waypoint 3: (11:40, 11:40)
waypoint 4: (11:45, 11:45)
waypoint 5: (11:50, 11:50)
waypoint 6: (12:09, 12:09)
waypoint 7: (12:21, 12:21)

Why is the solution windows has no flexibility anymore? Why waypoint 1 can be done within almost an hour but then loose all flexibility once using the SlackVar?
What are my misunderstandings?
Where are my mistakes?

is the solution valid?

the formula is cumulvar(next(i)) == cumulvar(i) + transition(i, next(i)) + slack(i)
If you fix all slacks, you remove all flexibility. Instead of fixing them, just add a lower bound.
dimension.SlackVar(index).SetMin(loading_time)


This is what I used to solve a VRPTW with service times. The CumulVar of any index in the time_dimension here suggests the time it starts servicing(loading/unloading) at that location.
        def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
            """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
            # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
            if from_index == to_index:
                return 0
            from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
            to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
            return service_times[from_node] + time_matrix[from_node][to_node]

        transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

        # Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

        # Add Time Windows constraint.
        time = "Time"
        routing.AddDimension(
            transit_callback_index,
            self.total_shift_time,  # allow waiting time
            self.total_shift_time,  # maximum time per vehicle
            False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
            time,
        )
        time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)

        # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
        for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(time_windows):
            if location_idx == location_mapping[self.depot][0]:
                continue
            index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
            earliest_start = time_window[0][0]
            latest_end = time_window[len(time_window) - 1][1]
            time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(earliest_start, latest_end - service_times[location_idx])

